# Intermittent issue of PayPal Checkout Button not posting to PayPal

Tags: php, html, paypal

I'm having a weird problem that is very intermittent. In fact, I've never been able to reproduce it on my end, but a variety of customers have experienced it. Typically, it's with mobile IOS - new and old. Basically, when the customer reaches checkout, they click Check Out and they end up on PayPal's login page. No values from the form are passed, as if they just went to PayPal.com. We do get a lot of sales via PayPal, so not sure what percentage has this issues, but want to make sure we capture those sales. Doing a Google, I have seen people mention this, but not seeing any solid solutions.

Here is my form code:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_blank">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="Product Test 1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value='10.00' />
    <input type="hidden" name="quantity_1" value="1" />
    <input type='hidden' name='item_number_1' value='' />
    <input type="hidden" name="shipping_1" value='8.00' />
    <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="2" />
    <input type="image" id="PayPalButton" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/i/buttons/checkout-logo-large.png" name="submit" class="wp_cart_checkout_button" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!" />
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="https://www.example.com/thankyou/?a=1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="https://www.example.com/paypal/" />
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="paypal@example.com" />
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" />
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart" />
    <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2" />
    <input type="hidden" name="charset" value="utf-8" />
    <input type="hidden" name="mrb" value="3FWGC6LFTMTUG" />
    <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="cart=58597ef8bdd56c789946533a9c1d0d1c&x=337917&email=test@example.com&ip=6xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" />
</form>
```

I've seen people remove target="paypal" and use target="_self". I've only used target="_blank". I don't want to use GET method since I could have lot of variables depending on how large the cart is. Every time I test (desktop, table, phone), the paypal process works. So not sure what is stopping some of the users.